# AngularJS ng-repeat search filters on different objects

Tags: angularjs

I have two array objects user and test. I am applying `ng-repeat` on the test and also put search filter it works for test object but not for the user object.

My code is

```
      <label>Search</label>
  <input ng-model="searchTest" type="text">
<div ng-repeat="t in list = (test | toArray | filter:searchTest | limitTo: maxLimit )"> 
    <td ng-bind="user[t.candidate].name"></td>
    <td ng-bind="user[t.candidate].place"></td>
   <td ng-bind="t.name"></td>
```

I'm unable to search the test using candidate name and place.

Comment: can you create Fiddler for the same. ?

Answer (score 0):

Also, perhaps not related to the question directly, but it looks like your code has a  inside a  then 's - which is not good html. If you're going to do something like that, put the ng-repeat on a .